Finding SAR baseband recordings?
I'm looking for openly available baseband recordings of synthetic aperture radar signals. Can anyone point me to archives of these?  Ideally I'd like to look at the signal from something like AN/FPS-85 (either very old or recent).
Alternatively, is there a satellite that consistently transmits SAR over/at California? (So far I've tried recording multiple overhead passes of Radarsat-2, Sentinel 1-A, RCM 1 through 3, all on 5405 MHz, and I've only picked up one good recording, possibly because the SAR transmitters are not always on or not aimed at my ground location.)
I'm not looking for any confidential information, just trying to understand the essential characteristics of the actual transmitted signals as I learn about SAR.
Thanks for any help!

Have you tried Umbra? They have a satellite constellation with a lot of open source data. Maybe they have some at your location.

If I understand correctly Umbra (and sites like it, such as ASF) download processed bounce data from earth imaging satellites, and distribute that to end users.  To be clear, I'm looking for recordings of the original transmitted SAR RF signal, ideally in some I/Q format.

What do you mean by "understanding the essential characteristics of the actual transmitted signals"? Most are LFMs, so there is not much to it. You don't have to actually record the waveform from the ground.

@always_learning as said above, the transmit waveforms are typically just LFMs, and usually the characteristics (PD, PRF, etc) comes in the metadata. I think they also come with a reference range, so you could use the info to build a reference waveform.

It occured to me that the ESA actually publishes their imaging schedule for sentinel, so you could use that to predict when a good time to record will be.

I am not aware of the anybody that would make AN/FPS-85-type data available.
Some SAR operators are pretty open about what they transmit though. Typically just a regular old LFM that is usually dechirpped on receive. The bandwidth is usually always available from the meta data distributed with the radar data, though not sure about the pulse duration. If it's not, you might be able to back it out from the sigma-0 values or just ask them -- I doubt the pulse length is a big secret for places like umbra. Either way, if it's dechirpped on receive, then that means the waveform is removed before it is even digitized, so in those cases (which is probably most of the high-res cases) what you want does not exist even to the satellite operators. If you can get the chirp rate, which places like umbra might include in their released data, you can always rechirp the pulses. (I am not sure what you gain from doing that though.)
So, given the publicly available meta data (transmit power, transmit positions, and transmit times, as well as antenna size), you should be able to approximate pretty well what the raw waveforms would look like at any point on the ground that is reasonably close to the aimpoint..
The ESA makes all of their Sentinel-1 radar data available. It's course range resolution data that covers very large ground areas, so it's probably not dechirpped on receive.
Lincoln Labs used to make some of their ka-band ADTS data available, but this is pushing back the clock to the 1990s.
As for recording their data from the ground, you don't have to be somewhere interesting but it does help. Since you will suffer only r^2 loss rather than r^4, you should be able to pick up a lot from their sidelobes and should not have to be in the mainbeam of the footprint. However, these platforms are limited in how many collections they can do a day and tend to only image "interesting" places. I would guess that California is not that interesting to US and Canadian operators. Another thing to consider is that the transmit waveform may be severely distorted once you go out 10+ sidelobes from boresight. (Antenna designers just don't really care what happens out there as long as it's low power.)
I would try recording all of the known SARs if you are able to. The German and Italian ones are pretty active from what I understand. Since you don't know the imaging schedule, anytime it's visible you should be recording and looking for activity. If you detect something, keep the data; otherwise, just flush it and move on to the next opportunity.
